# install openstack compute on VM (yoga release)

Tags: openstack, centos8, openstack-nova

I try install openstack compute service on Centos 8 in Virtualbox. I following instruction: https://docs.openstack.org/nova/yoga/install/compute-install-rdo.html

But when I try start services get error:

```
vsystemctl status libvirtd.service openstack-nova-compute.service
● libvirtd.service - Virtualization daemon
  Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/libvirtd.service; enabled; vendor preset: 
  enabled)
 Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2023-11-03 21:17:08 MSK; 1min 22s ago
 Docs: man:libvirtd(8)
       https://libvirt.org
Main PID: 2529 (libvirtd)
Tasks: 19 (limit: 32768)
Memory: 14.8M
CGroup: /system.slice/libvirtd.service
       └─2529 /usr/sbin/libvirtd --timeout 120

  Nov 03 21:17:08 compute.openstack.local systemd[1]: Starting Virtualization daemon...
  Nov 03 21:17:08 compute.openstack.local systemd[1]: Started Virtualization daemon.
  Nov 03 21:17:08 compute.openstack.local libvirtd[2529]:36:36, )
  Nov 03 21:17:08 compute.openstack.local libvirtd[2529]: hostname: 
  compute.openstack.local
  Nov 03 21:17:08 compute.openstack.local libvirtd[2529]: Unable to open /dev/kvm: No 
  such file or directory

  ● openstack-nova-compute.service - OpenStack Nova Compute Server
  Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/openstack-nova-compute.service; enabled; 
  vendor preset: disabled)
  Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2023-11-03 21:17:09 MSK; 1min 20s ago
  Process: 2575 ExecStart=/usr/bin/nova-compute (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
  Main PID: 2575 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

  Nov 03 21:17:09 compute.openstack.local systemd[1]: openstack-nova-compute.service: 
  Failed with result 'exit-code'.
  Nov 03 21:17:09 compute.openstack.local systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenStack Nova 
  Compute Server.
  Nov 03 21:17:09 compute.openstack.local systemd[1]: openstack-nova-compute.service: 
  Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
  Nov 03 21:17:09 compute.openstack.local systemd[1]: openstack-nova-compute.service: 
  Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
  Nov 03 21:17:09 compute.openstack.local systemd[1]: Stopped OpenStack Nova Compute 
  Server.
  Nov 03 21:17:09 compute.openstack.local systemd[1]: openstack-nova-compute.service: 
  Start request repeated too quickly.
  Nov 03 21:17:09 compute.openstack.local systemd[1]: openstack-nova-compute.service: 
  Failed with result 'exit-code'.
  Nov 03 21:17:09 compute.openstack.local systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenStack Nova 
  Compute Server.
```

How it fixing ?

Since I'm installing on VM I configure libvirt to use QEMU instead of KVM.

```
  etc/nova/nova.conf
  [libvirt]
  # ...
  virt_type = qemu
```

Comment: Not sure if that assumption is correct, but libvirt seems to require the kvm module to run. Can you verify if `lsmod | grep kvm` shows something? Maybe you need to modprobe it and restart?

Comment: I tried loading the kvm module. It didn't work.
```
[root@compute /]# lsmod | grep kvm
kvm                   962560  0
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
```
I checked  CPU does not support hardware acceleration, because I using VM.

So I used the Openstack installation instruction ("your compute node does not support hardware acceleration and you must configure libvirt to use QEMU instead of KVM.") and set `virt_type = qemu`, but get fail.

Comment: So just to clarify, you're using nested virtualization? Meaning you try to deploy a compute node as a virtual machine, correct? There a couple of things to check, but I don't have any strong suggestions. Can you check if you can install something like qemu-kvm? I use nested virtualization as well and it works on openSUSE and Ubuntu. But I see qemu-kvm installed on the compute node, so maybe that'll allow at least /dev/kvm to be present?